# With Latest MacBook Pro and Radeon 460 Graphics, How To Tell How Much Memory in Use?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, graphics, parallels-desktop

I've got the latest MacBook Pro with the touch bar.  4GB Graphics memory and I'm trying to figure out how much graphics memory is in use when I run certain apps.  I also run Parallels which dedicates part of that memory to itself so I want to make sure I don't starve it for my normal mac use.

I can see in Activity monitor that what I'm running requires High Perf GPU but I can't tell how much memory is being used.

Where can I see that memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).

Here's a direct quote from their website:

> CPU & GPU
>
> Realtime CPU graphs and a list of the top 5 CPU resource hogs. CPU
>   usage can be tracked by individual cores or with all cores combined,
>   to save menubar space.
>
> Plus, GPU memory and processor usage on supported Macs, and the active
>   GPU can be shown in the menubar.

In addition to the above, iStat Menus monitors a whole range of things that you may find useful.

You can download it for a 14 day trial to test it out prior to purchase.

**NOTE:** I have no affiliation whatsoever with iStat Menus.

Comment: I use iStat Menus and it is a fantastic program.

Comment: I use it too - completely rocks.